# Is a nightly curfew an effective intervention strategy for limiting the spread of an infectious disease?

Tags: population-biology, epidemiology, infectious-diseases

The governing bodies of several geographic areas hit by disease outbreaks will sometimes impose a nightly curfew on their citizens, restricting or limiting the ability of their citizens from going outside during certain hours of the night (or day). As I write this, several United States local or state governments are implementing such strategies in March 2020 to contain the COVID-2019 coronavirus pandemic ([Puerto Rico](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/15/us/coronavirus-puerto-rico.html) and [Hoboken, New Jersey](https://www.foxnews.com/us/hoboken-in-nj-imposes-strict-nightly-curfew-in-coronavirus-clampdown) both have nightly curfews as of March 15, 2020).

My question is: does any data exist showing that these measures are effective, or counter-productive? My intuition is that a nightly curfew could actually accelerate the spread of an infectious disease, because citizens who have to leave their homes to do errands are all obligated to do them during a shorter time-window, thereby raising the number of people present in public places at any one time. I couldn't find any published research directly assessing the effectiveness of nightly curfews as an epidemic response strategy. (I only found articles such as [this one](https://academic.oup.com/heapol/article/32/2/205/2568849) discussing the failure of nightly curfews in Liberia during the 2014 Ebola epidemic, but those caused public rioting and low compliance). Considering how common this is frequently mentioned and attempted as an intervention strategy, what were the results? Is there any published data from real-world examples, or even results from model simulations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted to Medical Sciences.

Comment: Cleaned up the comments since they are rather moot now that the question is closed; the discussion can continue on Meta. My personal view is this question is on-topic both at Biology.SE and MedicalSciences.SE, but I'm strongly opposed to cross-posting. A mod at MedicalSciences says it's fine there, so I'd rather close here and instead direct people to https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21448/is-a-nightly-curfew-an-effective-intervention-strategy-for-limiting-the-spread-o